# cannot get rid of sr.lock files while FOR LOOPING dbfTables

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000732

I am new to Python and to this community as well, hope someone could help me.
I am running  script to extract and merge toghether the tables of some Raster. Each Attribute Table presents only one row and the same field names.
My script works fine until the very end of it, when I try to merge all the tables. It seems the tables are locked (I can see an "sr.lock" file for each Table I want to merge in my folder) and I cannot access them.
Strange thing: I do access them if I simply use a sample (for instance) of two of these so created tables in the Python window within arcMap and type their names instead of using a FOR LOOPING... Guess it might have to do with the 
Here is my script:
    #import relevant modules, create geoprocessing dispatch object
    import win32com.client, sys, string, os, arcpy

```
gp = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.gpDispatch.1")

# Remember to change this to wherever your files are stored
gp.workspace = "G:\\Chile_2012\\MODIS10A2.V005\\provvisoria\\ATTRIBUTE_TABLE"
out_dir = "G:\\Chile_2012\\MODIS10A2.V005\\provvisoria\\ATTRIBUTE_TABLE"

try:
    rasters = gp.ListRasters("*", "all")
    rasters.reset()
    rst = rasters.Next()

    while rst:
        # Create the new field
        gp.AddField_management (rst, "FILENAME", "text", "", "", "50")

        # Apply the filename to all entries       
        gp.CalculateField_management (rst, "FILENAME", '"' + rst + '"')
        rst = rasters.Next()

except:
    print gp.GetMessages ()

listRaster = arcpy.ListRasters ()

for raster in listRaster:
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion (raster, out_dir, raster+ '.dbf')

listTable = arcpy.ListTables ()

for table in listTable:
    arcpy.Merge_management (table, 'Cl_Rio_Aconcagua.dbf')
```

The code is taken from others, I simply adapted it for my needs. Anyway, the error I am receiving so far doesn't have to do explicitly with LOCK topics, but since I have those files in my folder I need help to find out how to get rid of them.

```
ERROR 000732: Input Datasets: Dataset 'Cl_Rio_Aconcagua_2007121.img.dbf' does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Merge)
```

Comment: I've also tried the Merge without the FOR looping (which seems not necessary), but still have problems with the "Dataset xxx does not exist or is not supported".

Comment: Solved. It was just a problem with the Merge function cannot reading dbf files, only table views, so I simply modified the output of TableToTable, excluding the extension and changing the name not to be the same of the input, and everything worked so far!

Comment: Please write a proper reply and then accept it (as per the FAQ). Nice that you managed to solve it by yourself and consider yourself lucky for not running into locking issues. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a matter of LOCK files. I've just red the help of the Merge_management tool in the ESRI website and couldn't find any reference to dBase tables, therefore I just tried to avoid inserting the extension ".dbf" in the output of the TableToTable_conversion tool and, since I set the name of the output to different than the input by appending a simple "Tab_" prefix, everythinf worked fine so far.

Sorry for the misunderstanding. Anyway, now the task has moved to another topic, You can see it here if You like [Create temporary files as intermediate output to be used as input in concatenation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32635/create-temporary-files-as-intermediate-output-to-be-used-as-input-in-concatenati).